# How to launch chromebrowser using chrome options?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Without using The System.setProperty

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");`

I have tried to launch the chrome browser using chrome options with the below code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

i have set my chromedriver path in my System variables.It not Working can any figure this out.

[image: Path to My Chrome Driver]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please try below code as set `Binary` also into `Options` to launch chromeBrowser:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\raheela.aslam\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");  //Path where the Chrome.exe exist in your machine.
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chrome_driver\\chromedriver.exe"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Without using system.setProperty can't we launch the browser? @Raheela Aslam

Comment: According to the documentation it looks we need to provide that https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html 
other Option is try with latest Chrome Driver.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubt, now working , but how to find the binary path for chrome in my pc? am Not Asking about the path for chrome driver, am asking about binary path you have included .

Comment: Please find where the Chrome is installed like as I have in my Program Files "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"

Comment: Got it , Working Thanks For Clearing

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to launch chrome without setting property. This downloads the latest chrome driver version and starts it. You can use WebDriverManager within using bonigarcia dependency.

[bonigarcia dependency](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: This is using Marven right?in pom.xml we need to add the dependencies right?

Comment: exactly. putting bonigarcia dependency into your pom.xml and running the simple code above will launch your chrome. you can also do it for firefox too.