# SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context' with Chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image: Runtime error]

[image: Actual Code]

Error stack trace (Updated from comments):

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 7778 Only local connections are allowed. 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"961185F0AA38D24650EF6C797BC32535","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"} 
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102) 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) 
Command duration or timeout: 1.68 seconds Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:58:41' 
System info: host: 'LTAH024', ip: '192.168.131.142', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60' 
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

I wrote simple program to launching a chrome browser. Please see the below code. I have already set a path in environment variable:

```
package automationFramework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeBrowser {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver drive = new ChromeDriver();

    drive.get("http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/running-tests-in-chrome-browser/");

    System.out.println("Successfully open tools qa website in Chrome browser");
    //Thread.sleep(5000); //To initiate thread , we need to add throws interrupt exception

    //Close the driver
    //driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Please look into this and help me out. The same thing `geckodriver` for firefox is working.

Comment: can you have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257059/how-to-launch-chromebrowser-using-chrome-options/53257102#53257102 you need to first create options.

Comment: Please do not post images, post your actual stacktrace/code as text here

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 7778 Only local connections are allowed. 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"961185F0AA38D24650EF6C797BC32535","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"} 
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102) 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) 
Command duration or timeout: 1.68 seconds Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:58:41' 
System info: host: 'LTAH024', ip: '192.168.131.142', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60' 
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

You have 3 issues exactly and your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.2.20*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.20*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.20/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v43-48**

- You are using *chrome=70.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.43*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is the current version of **3.141.5**..
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_60** which is pretty **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u60* , *Selenium Client v3.141.5* , *ChromeDriver v2.20* and the *Chrome Browser v70.0*

### Solution

- While using *Selenium v3.x* clients you need to download the latest **ChromeDriver** from [**ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) store it anywhere within your system and provide the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* through **`System.setProperty()`** line as follows:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  ```
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u191**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.43**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v69-71*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.43 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: could you please help me by answering this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332840/best-automation-tool-for-testing-desktop-based-plm-system

Answer (score 0):

[Download chrome driver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), keep it at your local and put the path at `System.setProperty` try the below code, hope it helps.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeBrowser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "B:\\chromedriver.exe"); //put driver path here
        WebDriver drive = new ChromeDriver();

        drive.get("http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/running-tests-in- chrome-browser/");
        System.out.println("Successfully open tools qa website in Chrome browser");
        drive.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: My system is built on 64 bit version of an operating system installed. and given chrome driver was 32 bit version , so is it make difference?

Comment: Hello guys,  it has been working now, only issue was new Download chrome driver. I replace this from old one and its working now. Thanks to all. @Al Imran ,koushick,DebanjanB and rest ones.

Answer (score 0):

Their are Three Ways to open The Chrome Browser:

**First one:using system.setproperty**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

**Second one : using Chrome Options:**

```
//set path to chromedriver.exe

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        options.setBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"));
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Last one : if you are using maven use this**

This downloads the latest chrome driver version and starts it. You can use WebDriverManager within using bonigarcia dependency. Add The bonigarcia dependency in your Pom.xml File and start using it via WebdriverManager

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Finally What is Version for your Gecko driver & Firefox?

Comment: FF version 59.1 and Gecko driver -> geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64

Comment: it Should Work! Any Error Message you are getting for firefox?

Comment: if you are using selenium 3 , please update the chrome browser and try the code above i have mentioned